# Looking for a popular templating language that needs XSS protection

Tags: html, templates, template-engine

I'd like to experiment with a popular HTML templating language to see if I can solve XSS problems in it.  What is a popular, open-source, templating language that I could try to tackle.

By templating language, I mean a language used to generate an output language by combining static content in that output language with dynamic data from another source.  E.g. PHP is commonly used as a templating language for HTML/CSS/JS, and XSLT is a templating language for XML.

The ideal template language would be

1. Widely used
2. Open source
3. Not have already solved XSS
4. The simpler the syntax the better

The idea is to

1. parse each template so that I end up with a tree of chunks of raw HTML, expressions that produce dynamic values that need to be encoded, and conditional (switch/if) and loop constructs.
2. walk the tree inferring context.  Possible contexts might include (HTML_PCDATA, IN_JS_DBL_QUOTED_STR, etc.)  So if I see a chunk of raw HTML, `<a href="` in an HTML PCDATA context, then I move to a context where I am expecting part of a URL.  When I reach a branch or loop, follow each branch independently, and join the contexts afterwards.
3. if the language has templates, try to determine a static call graph so I can clone templates and rewrite calls where a given template is called in multiple contexts.
4. wrap the expressions that produce dynamic values with calls into a library I implement that includes functions like `expectHtml(...)`, `expectJsValue(...)` that encode the dynamic value appropriately.  E.g. `expectHtml(...)` converts `<` to `&lt;`.
5. provide some convenience functions so that the code that provies data to templates can use RTTI to specify the language of dynamic values to avoid overescaping.  So `expectHtml(...)` would not escape a value of type `Html` since it is assumed to come from a safe source like `knownSafeHtml(...)` or `stripBadTags(...)`

Comment: Not really a templating language, but how about "plain vanilla" PHP, JSP or ASP without utilizing the provided XSS escaping facilities?

Comment: I don't think you are going to find anything that is widely used that has XSS vulnerabilities. That is like asking for a widely used car that doesn't have any brakes. If it has that big of a security issue, it's not going to be widely used. As BalusC mentioned you'll probably need to use an existing framework with the XSS prevention removed.

Comment: @Brent, PHP, JSP, and ASPs are widely used and applications written in them are rife with XSS problems.  Perhaps, to rephrase my question, does the language's equivalent of "Hello, $world" open up an XSS vulnerability if $world is controlled by an attacker.  cheers, mike

Comment: @BalusC, JSP might be a good last resort.  A published grammar.  Widely used to write vulnerable apps.  And as a bonus, has a compilation pipeline I might be able to plug my code into.  It is a large language though.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your request. When you say templating language I thought you meant something like Smarty. Taking that in to consideration, then I would imagine that most common web languages fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Brent.  Will add a definition of templating language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upcoming Symfony is broken down in components. They are releasing them one by one. [Symfony Templating](http://components.symfony-project.org/templating/) is one of them and would be a good candidate for you to test.